# SQL violation of Primary Key constraint on update

Tags: sql, sql-server, key

**--EDITED--**

I think I figured out the problem. The original row is being taken to update instead of the latest row therefore the `CreationDate` is the same and since `ID + CreationDate` is the primary key it returns a violation. Is there any way to select the latest row instead of the original row when updating records?

Thanks :D

**----------------**

[image]

I got the error violation of primary key constraint but I don't know why because my primary key values are unique.

I can add the record for 'Darren' and update it once. After that I get the error. My trigger works such that when I update an existing record, both the original and edited record are inserted into the table ProcessList so that I am able to see all the changes made to all records.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcessList
(
    TransactionID       integer         IDENTITY,
    IsEdited            bit             DEFAULT 'FALSE',
    ID                  integer         NOT NULL,
    Name                varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    Amount              smallmoney      NOT NULL,
    CreationDate        datetime        DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ModificationDate    datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, CreationDate)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProcessListHist
(
    TransactionID       integer         IDENTITY,
    IsEdited            bit             DEFAULT 'FALSE',
    ID                  integer         NOT NULL,
    Name                varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
    Amount              smallmoney      NOT NULL,
    CreationDate        datetime        DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    ModificationDate    datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, CreationDate)
)
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CloneAfterUpdate ON ProcessList
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    IF (UPDATE (Amount) OR UPDATE (NAME))
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO ProcessListHist (ID, Name, Amount, CreationDate, ModificationDate, IsEdited)
            SELECT 
                ID, Name, Amount, CreationDate, GETDATE(), 'True'
            FROM deleted

        UPDATE PL
        SET PL.CreationDate = PLH.ModificationDate
        FROM ProcessList PL
        INNER JOIN deleted ON PL.ID = deleted.ID 
                           AND PL.CreationDate = deleted.CreationDate
        INNER JOIN ProcessListHist PLH ON PL.ID = PLH.ID 
                                       AND PLH.CreationDate = deleted.CreationDate

        INSERT INTO ProcessList (ID, Name, Amount, CreationDate, ModificationDate, IsEdited)
            SELECT 
                ID, Name, Amount, CreationDate, ModificationDate, IsEdited
            FROM ProcessListHist
END
```

Insert/Update statements:

```
INSERT INTO ProcessList (ID, Name, Amount) VALUES ('1020', 'Darren', '300')
UPDATE ProcessList SET Amount = 1000 WHERE Name = 'Darren'
```

Comment: Can you check your table records if there are no NULL id ?

Answer (score 1):

You logging a transaction on your history table right ? , therefore you need to remove the ID of history table from being unique. Make it `TransactionID INT` only, not an identity, your problem is because every time you perform an `UPDATE` , the record is inserted into history table, so if the record already exist **meaning to say, if the ID is already existing in the history table , you are not allowed to insert the same ID**, that's why you will receiving that error.

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work. Still returns the same error.

Comment: @eyeballs , did you try it in your 2 tables ? `ProcessList` and `ProcessListHist` , remove the the ID from being unique.. make it only INT.. so that when the trigger fires and that `INSERT` statement detect the same ID in the history table, it will still insert.

Comment: oh but i need the identity so that transactionID will be unique and can be used to track records :<

Comment: @eyeballs , you can still insert the TransactionID but not uniquely because you are performing an update record, updating a record will insert the same transactionid in history table, so if your transaction id is unique (identity) , it will cause an error, but if your id is not define as unique, you can still insert the same ID without error.